# ¿Es posible combinar diseño de storyboard con SwiftUI?

Tags: swift

Eh estado trabajando en un diseño con storyboard, el cual se me hace mucho más limitado que SwiftUi en cuestión de diseño, es posible crear una combinación de ambos en un proyecto? , por ejemplo, crear un botón personalizado con SwiftUI y poder llamarlo en el storyboard para que se vea en el producto final.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen de muestra de un login hecho con SwiftUI(izquierda) y Storyboard(derecha).

Actualización : Utilizando el método UIHostingController lo eh podido lograr, dejo el código a continuación

```
    import UIKit
  import CoreData
 import SwiftUI

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

var Documentos : [NSManagedObject] = []

fileprivate let contentViewHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIViewLogIn())



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    setupHostingController()
    setupConstraints()
    
}
func setupConstraints() {
    contentViewHostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    contentViewHostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint (equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    contentViewHostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.bottomAnchor).isActive=true
    contentViewHostingController.view.leftAnchor.constraint (equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    contentViewHostingController.view.rightAnchor.constraint (equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
}
func setupHostingController(){
    addChild(contentViewHostingController)
    view.addSubview(contentViewHostingController.view)
    contentViewHostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
    
}
```

}

Comment: Con [UIHostingController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontroller) puedes agregar SwiftUI a UIKit. Igual hay bastantes ejemplos si le revisas a fondo.

Comment: Eh probado el método de UIHostingController y me ah funcionado, muchas gracias!